# Understanding phrase "feed right back to him"

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following usage of `feed` I came across in the `Inceprion` mopvie:

> The vultures are circling. The sicker Maurice Fischer becomes, the
>   more powerful Peter Browning becomes. I've had ample opportunity to
>   observe Browning, adopt his physical presence, to study his
>   mannerisms, and so on and so forth. Now, the first layer of the dream,
>   I can impersonate Browning and suggest to Fischer's conscious mind.
>   When we take him a level deeper, his own projection of Browning should
>   – should ***feed*** that right back to him.

I've found two meaning of `feed back`:

> to have an influence on the development of something by reacting to it
>   in some way

and

> to give information or opinions about something, especially so that it
>   can be improved

And I have a trouble to understand which one is suitable in the context?

As far as I understand in *feed that **right** back to him* right is used to emphasize something, but I can't get the point what exact it emphasize.

Comment: Synonym for "send" or "transmit" or "route". You can think of it as a video or audio "feed". Right=directly.

Comment: Award yourself a gold star! You're absolutely right that the primary significance of ***right*** there is to add emphasis. That role could also (less commonly) be fulfilled using ***straight*** or ***directly***. Fro which you may be able to see how ***right*** here emphasizes *no significant deviation or attenuation*. I've no idea what's going on between Browning and Fischer here, but apparently once Fischer is able to "project" Browning, he'll be able to *experience* that projection ***faithfully** reproduced back to himself* (so it'll be a strong/convincing experience).

Comment: @TRomano Could you clarify own projection of Browning should feed right back to who? To Fischer or to Browning?

Comment: As I read the (less than crystal-clear) passage, it goes: When we take him [Fischer] a level deeper, his own [i.e. Fischer's own] projection of Browning should--should feed that [unclear antecedent] right back [i.e. directly back] to him [to Fischer].

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. As far as I understand what you said in your comment is _feed back_ synonim for _send_, _transmit_ or _route_. So the meaning _to give information or opinions about something, especially so that it can be improved_ is right there for _feed back_, is it?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: To *feed {something} back* means to direct it back to its source.  You're right, it's usually information of some kind, or an analogue or digital signal that encodes information.  But there are no connotations of "improvement" in this process.  I believe you're thinking of "feedback" (positive or negative criticism), which is often invited by websites, for example, so that they can hear what users think of the website, and thereby identify improvements that should be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site describes in detail the scene and characters from Inception.

http://inception.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Browning
http://inception.wikia.com/wiki/Eames

In the second dream level, the team used Fischer’s projection of Browning (who appear slightly more arrogant then in reality) to their advantage. Once the projection was captured by the team, they encouraged Fisher to believe that Browning arranged his kidnapping. Once Fischer believed them, the projection conformed to Fischer’s new perspective of him and admitted doing so. He claimed the will was Maurice’s attempt to taunt Robert for not being worthy of his accomplishments, while this was a combination of the idea’s Eames planted and Fischer’s own perception of his father.

The main reason for this was to have Fischer transfer his resentment of his father to Browning, thus repairing his view of his father and allowing him to attain emotional renewal. After Fischer wakes up, he may feel suspicion and resentment toward Browning, but will not be consciously aware why.